# Rails - Simple Form & Nesting models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have three models in my Rails 4 app.

I have a projects, project questions and a project answers model.

Projects

```
has_many :project_questions, dependent: :destroy#, through: :projects
accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_questions
```

Project questions has these associations:

```
  belongs_to :project#, counter_cache: true
  has_many :project_answers, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_answers
```

Project answers associations are:

```
 belongs_to :project_question#, counter_cache: true  
belongs_to :user
```

My routes.rb has:

```
  resources :projects do
  # patch '/toggle-draft', to 'projects#toggle_draft', as: 'toggle_draft'
    resources :project_questions do
      resources :project_answers
    end
  end
```

In my projects_controller, I have permitted params for project questions and answers as follows:

```
 project_question_attributes: [:title, :content, :user_id, :project_id,
      project_answer_attributes: [:answer, :project_question_id]],
```

These params are also permitted in the Project questions and project answers controllers.

In my projects view, I want to render a partial that I have made in my project_questions view folder.

In projects show page, I have:

```
  <%= link_to 'Ask a question', new_project_question_path %> <% end %>
  <%= render 'project_questions/pqps' %>
```

In my project_questions partial which is called _pqps, I have;

```
<div class="containerfluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

      <% f.simple_fields_for :project_questions, @project.project_questions.build do |q| %>
          <div class="categorytitle">
            <%= q.title %>
          </div>
          <div class="generaltext">
            <%= q.content %>
          </div>
          <%= render 'project_answers/show' %>
          <span class="editproject">   <% if current_user.id ==  @project.creator_id %>
            <%= link_to 'Answer this question', new_project_answer_path %>
              <% end %>
          </span>

      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, when I try this, I get an error that says:

```
undefined local variable or method `new_project_question_path'
```

Can anyone see what i've done wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What is the route name you are getting for project_question#new, when you run `rake routes`. Shouldn't it be `new_project_project_question_path`

Comment: if nested routes are written

Comment: new_project_project_question GET      /projects/:project_id/project_questions/new(.:format)                                           project_questions#new

Comment: I get this error: No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"project_questions", :id=>"54"} missing required keys: [:project_id]

Comment: Do you really have to nest your routes under `:projects` namespace? Why not just define the routes separately?

Comment: You need to pass the project to the path: `new_project_project_question_path(@project)`

Comment: @Marcus Do we ever need to pass id to **new**

Comment: @Abhi Since it's nested the new resource must know which projects it's going to be associated with?

Comment: Then as per the error mentioned in comments, it should be `new_project_project_question_path(:project_id => @project.id)`

Comment: `/projects/:project_id/project_questions/new(.:format)` only takes one parameter, so it shouldn't be needed, but it doesn't hurt to be thorough :)